Kernel of Vandermonde matrix mod $p^k$
Consider an $n \times n\ $ Vandermonde matrix $A$ whose entries are elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$, and all $x_i$ from which the matrix is formed are distinct.
Let $K = \text{ker}(A) = \{\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{Z}^n / p^k\mathbb{Z}^n \mid A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}\}$.
Let $l$ be the greatest integer such that $K \mod p^l = \{\mathbf{0}\}$. In other words,
$K$ is trivial when all its elements are taken mod $p^l$.
I've made some tests and $l$ is much larger than I expected.
For example, with $p = 2, k = 64, n = 40, x_i = i+1$, I got $l = 29$.
With $x_i$ as random numbers $l$ varies a lot but it still obtains relatively large values.
How come?
This is the code I tested with: code
Also, note that I have practically zero knowledge of linear algebra / modules.

There are two ways to write the Vandermonde matrix and they differ by a transpose, and the answer could depend on which one you use; are you using the Vandermonde matrix whose first column is all $1$s, or first row?

@QiaochuYuan I'm using the version where the first column is all 1s.

Note that each vector $\mathbf v \in \Bbb R^n$ corresponds to a degree $n-1$ polynomial, and $A \mathbf v$ produces the value of this polynomial at each $x_i$. The kernel of $A$, then, corresponds to the polynomials that are zero for all inputs $x_i$. Apparently, you are finding polynomials $f$ of degree $n-1$ for which $f(1) = \cdots = f(n) = 0$.

Why were you expecting $\ell$ to be small?

As Ben Grossman says in the comments, $Av$ is the linear map which sends a vector of coefficients $(v_0, \dots v_{n-1})$ to the vector of values of the polynomial $v(x) = \sum v_j x^j$ at the values $x_i$. So the kernel $K$ can be identified with the vector space of polynomials of degree $\le n-1$ which vanish on the $n$ distinct values $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}/p^k$.
From here I am going to specialize to your example $p = 2, k = 64, n = 40, x_i = i + 1$ for simplicity. Assuming $i$ is indexed starting from $0$, you want a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $\le 39$ which vanishes $\bmod 2^{64}$ on $\{ 1, \dots 40 \}$. Suppose $f(x)$ is such a polynomial. We can write it in the Newton basis
$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{39} f_i (x - 1)_i$$
where $(x - 1)_i = (x - 1) \dots (x - i)$ is the falling factorial. Plugging in the conditions $f(1) = f(2) = \dots = f(40) \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64}$ gives us a triangular system of equations for the $f_i$, the first few of which are
$$f_1 \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64}$$
$$2f_1 + 2f_2 \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64} \Leftrightarrow f_2 \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{63}$$
$$3f_1 + 6f_2 + 6f_3 \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64} \Leftrightarrow f_3 \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{63}$$
and so forth. We can organize this computation by writing it in terms of forward differences. If we set $(\Delta f)(x) = f(x + 1) - f(x)$ then we have that
$$\Delta (x - 1)_i = i (x - 1)_{i-1}$$
and if $f$ vanishes on $\{ 1, \dots 40 \}$ then $\Delta f$ vanishes on $\{ 1, \dots 39 \}$. Iterating, the $j^{th}$ forward difference
$$(\Delta^j f)(x) = \sum_{i=j}^{39} f_i (i)_j (x - 1)_{i-j}$$
vanishes on $\{ 1, \dots, 40 - j \}$, and plugging in $x = 1$ (which we can do for $j \le 39$) gives
$$f_j j! \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64}.$$
A necessary and sufficient condition for $f(x)$ to vanish on $\{ 1, \dots 40 \}$ is that $(\Delta^j f)(1) \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64}$ for $0 \le j \le 39$; this gives that a necessary and sufficient condition on the coefficients $f_j, 1 \le j \le 39$ is that they must satisfy
$$\boxed{ f_j \equiv 0 \bmod 2^{64 - \nu_2(j!)} }$$
where $\nu_2(j!)$ is the exponent of the largest power of $2$ dividing $j!$, which can be computed using Legendre's formula. A nice recursive way to write down Legendre's formula is the following: start with $j$ and iterate the map $x \mapsto \lfloor \frac{x}{2} \rfloor$, then add up the results. For $j = 39$ this gives
$$\nu_2(39!) = 19 + 9 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 35$$
which gives that all coefficients of the polynomial $f(x)$ are divisible by $2^{64 - 35} = 2^{29}$. This gives $\boxed{ \ell = 29 }$ as you've computed. For an explicit example, we get that the polynomial
$$2^{29} (x - 1) \dots (x - 39)$$
vanishes $\bmod 2^{64}$ on $\{ 1, \dots 40 \}$. This is easy to verify: we only need to check that it vanishes at $x = 40$ and this follows from our calculation of $\nu_2(39!)$.
This calculation generalizes to general $p, k, n$ if we still ask for vanishing on $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$; we get that $\boxed{ \ell = k - \nu_p((n-1)!) }$, and $p^{\ell} (x - 1) \dots (x - (n-1))$ is an explicit example. For general $x_i$ you can still do a calculation in the Newton basis but if the $x_i$ aren't an arithmetic progression then you don't get this nice calculation in terms of a single forward difference. I think you can adapt the method of divided differences but then you have to deal with the issue that you can't always divide.
To get a sense for roughly how large this number is, we have the elementary upper bound $\nu_p(j!) \le \frac{j}{p-1}$ (this follows from removing the floor functions in Legendre's formula, then summing the geometric series), which gives $\boxed{ \ell \ge k - \frac{n-1}{p-1} }$.  For example, for $k = 64, n = 40, p = 2$ this gives $\ell \ge 64 - 39 = 25$.
